# Can I carry spare Lithium-Ion batteries with me on Lufthansa?

Tags: lufthansa, prohibited-items, batteries

I am travelling from the US to India on Lufthansa. I have five spare Lithium-ion batteries, each 850mAh.

Can I bring them back safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Lufthansa, Dangerous Goods that may be carried under certain Conditions](http://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/75/media_1941993975.pdf) regulations (yours should be less than 10 Wh each):

> Portable electronic devices containing lithium metal or lithium-ion cells or batteries, such as  watches, calculating machines, cameras, cellular phones, laptop computers, camcorders, etc., when carried for personal  use.

```
Checked baggage:               up to 100 Wh, or 2g       Yes
                               100 - 160 Wh, or 2 - 8g    No  
Cabin baggage:                                           Yes
On one's person                                          Yes
Approval of carrier required:  up to 100 Wh, or 2g        No
                               100 - 160 Wh, or 2 - 8g   Yes
```

> **Rule:**
>   Batteries must meet the requirements of the UN Manual of Tests and Criteria, part III, section 38.3.
>
> **Rules for spare batteries:**
>   • Spare lithium metal or lithium ion cells or batteries with a Watt-hour rating up to 100 Wh for such consumer electronic devices:
>   - The user has to remove the battery.
>   - Allowed in cabin baggage only and in quantities for personal use only.
>   - These batteries must be individually protected to prevent short circuits.
>   • Each installed or spare battery must not exceed:
>   - For lithium metal or lithium alloy batteries a lithium content of more than 2g,
>    or
>   - For lithium ion batteries of a Watt hour rating of more than 100 Wh:
>   - Not more than two spare batteries per person.
>   - Allowed in cabin baggage only.
>   - Approval of the carrier is required.
>
> **Notes**
>   - E-cigarettes or other artificial smoking devices containing lithium batteries shall only be accepted on cabin baggage.
>   - Articles which are used as power source, e.g. power banks are considered as spare batteries.
>   - Samsung Galaxy Note 7 smartphones. The smartphone is neither allowed on board nor in the carry-on and checked baggage. Lufthansa Group does not offer any storage facilities at the airports.

Answer (score 3):

**YES**, for a US airline, but you must bring them as Carry On baggage.  You should not check them.  Many other airlines follow this guidance as well.

FAA: [Pack Safe
Lithium ion and lithium metal batteries, spare (uninstalled)](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/more_info/?hazmat=7)

Most airlines publish the guidelines on their web site so you can easily search for you specific case.

Example **Lufthansa**: [Carry-on baggage on Lufthansa](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Carry-on-baggage) 
and [Dangerous Goods that may be carried under certain Conditions](http://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/90/media_832590.pdf)